# How to populate real time data into a Twitter Bootstrap Admin Dashboard Theme

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jenkins

What script, tool or framework should i use to  populate live data like jenkins build queue , gitlab commits,  or open jira work items into the admin dashboard (see [this](http://bootstrapmaster.com/live/acme2/index.html) for a theme) - CORS, jquery, jasonp , feeds2js  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Learn Bootstrap

You need to visit and read and understand all examples/components/css features provided by Bootstrap. Before you do anything else read go here - http://getbootstrap.com/

You will need to understand atleast the following first

- [Bootstrap Installation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started)
- [CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css)
- [Components](http://getbootstrap.com/components)
- [Javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript)

### 2. About your theme

Now once you have done that, next is understanding the theme you have mentioned about. Its a theme from [BootstrapMaster](http://bootstrapmaster.com/) and the theme you seem to be using is [Acme dashboard](http://bootstrapmaster.com/live/acme2/index.html).

Your theme uses a lot of 3rd party plugin all of which are listed under the "External components" header here: http://bootstrapmaster.com/themes/admin-dashboard/acme-dashboard-responsive-admin-template/

### 3. External Components

Its uses many 3rd party components few of which are listed below

- The big center chart uses [Flot Charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/)
- Weekly stats chart uses [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about)
- Facebook/Twitter chart again uses [Flot Charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/)
- For Progress bar it uses the [default bootstrap progress bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).

The list really could go really big. The easiest way would be to inspect the component you need to know about, it will give away a hint of which plugin it uses from the list. And incase you have bought this theme you could ask the support they will be able to help you better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Flot charts and jquery sparklines are helping me have a plumbing between tools and extract real time data.. Thanks!